# How to get drag hover event outside the sortable element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using the Jquery sortable to short the list and it's working but need to drag hover when drag hover is outside the sortable element. In below html I need to drag hover on 'Upper' and 'Bottom'.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="upper">Upper</div>
    <ul id="slide">
      <li class="slide">Slide 1</li>
      <li class="slide">Slide 2</li>
      <li class="slide">Slide 3</li>
      <li class="slide">Slide 4</li>
      <li class="slide">Slide 5</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
</div>
```

And I apply the sortable on 'slide'.

```
$("#slide").sortable({
placeholder: 'slide-placeholder',
axis: "y",
revert: 150,
start: function(e, ui){

    placeholderHeight = ui.item.outerHeight();
    ui.placeholder.height(placeholderHeight + 15);
    $('<div class="slide-placeholder-animator" data-height="' + placeholderHeight + '"></div>').insertAfter(ui.placeholder);

},
change: function(event, ui) {

    ui.placeholder.stop().height(0).animate({
        height: ui.item.outerHeight() + 15
    }, 300);

    placeholderAnimatorHeight = parseInt($(".slide-placeholder-animator").attr("data-height"));

    $(".slide-placeholder-animator").stop().height(placeholderAnimatorHeight + 15).animate({
        height: 0
    }, 300, function() {
        $(this).remove();
        placeholderHeight = ui.item.outerHeight();
        $('<div class="slide-placeholder-animator" data-height="' + placeholderHeight + '"></div>').insertAfter(ui.placeholder);
    });

},
stop: function(e, ui) {

    $(".slide-placeholder-animator").remove();

}
});
```

CSS

```
body {
padding: 20px;
}
#slide {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 300px;
}
.slide {
padding: 15px;
background-color: #2F2F2F;
margin: 0 0 15px;
text-align: center;
color: #FFF;
border: 2px solid #444;
}

.slide-placeholder {
background: #DADADA;
position: relative;
}
.slide-placeholder:after {
content: " ";
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 15px;
background-color: #FFF;
}
.bottom, .upper{    
height: 30px;
text-align: center;
}
.container{width:300px;}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rakeshpatidar71/yg26uwny/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will happen when you bind droppable events.

```
$(".upper").droppable({
    over: function( event, ui ) {
       console.log('over');
    },
    out: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log('out');
    }
}); 
 $(".bottom").droppable({
    over: function( event, ui ) {
       console.log('over');
    },
    out: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log('out');
    }
});
```

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/rakeshpatidar71/nwf9tp4c/)